# Is there any code generation & optimisation tool for compiler (I had AST tree generated)?

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, compiler-optimization

I have go to the last step to making my own compiler .. 
Is there any tool (eclipse integration will be better) for generating assembly code and optimise it auto-matically if I had an AST.. 
If there are some toolkit exists , which one is better?

Comment: Take a look at [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM).

Comment: You might consider also Common Lisp and http://sbcl.org/

Comment: @Mysticial LLVM is great for going from a very low-level imperative IR to machine code. It's no good for going from an AST to very low-level imperative code. It certainly makes that last step easier, but creating LLVM IR from an AST for a high-level language is everything but trivial (depending on the language, much harder than an interpreter).

Comment: @delnan, it is trivial - becase LLVM will still do all the optimisations for you. You only have to do an ad hoc, trivial translation. The complexity is in a runtime support (e.g., implementing a garbage collector), not in compilation. But, you'll have the same problem with an interpreter, therefore, compiling even a high level language with LLVM is much easier than interpreting it.

Comment: @SK-logic I'm not talking about optimizations, I'm talking about getting correct and working LLVM IR. For example, unless I'm terribly wrong, writing a compiler from CPython bytecode to LLVM IR is harder than writing an interpreter for it in C. Even a simplistic translation whose output mirrors the actions of an interpreter has several additional concerns the interpreter doesn't have, simply because LLVM IR is more low-level than C code.

Comment: @SK-logic And then there's the fact that LLVM *doesn't* do all optimizations one might want. For example, as the Unladden Swallow guys notices, LLVM lacks many optimizations they want to perform on Python code. Alternatively, ask the GHC guys how fast GHC's output is if they omit all of their own optimizations and pass the unoptimized STG code to the LLVM backend.

Comment: @delnan, no, writing an ad hoc compiler from CPython bytecode to LLVM IR is trivial. Writing an efficient compiler from Python to whatever else is tricky. And, of course, implementing a runtime for Python is an awful lot of work. The trick is simple: if a semantic gap between language A and language B is too big, you can always introduce an intermediate language C in between. Still too big a gap? Add more intermediate language. All the way down to the dumbest possible chain of obvious, trivial transforms.

Comment: @delnan, LLVM will do all the necessary optimisations to mitigate any possible effect of doing an *ad hoc* translation (unnecessary loads/stores, etc.). Of course if you want more, you have to do it yourself, you have to do a language-specific optimisations in higher levels of a compilation chain. But OP asks for a "generic" solution, which implies that no language-specific issues are going to be considered.

Comment: @SK-logic If you add additional intermediate languages, each individual translation becomes simpler, but you have to write more translations. That doesn't simplify the total task arbitrarily, at best the total task gets easier *up to a point* (where the reduction in complexity isn't worth the additional effort to create more transformations and intermediate languages). Or perhaps you'll prove me wrong and easily create a CPython bytecode -> LLVM IR translator (using an existing runtime, e.g. CPython's)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21010/discussion-between-delnan-and-sk-logic)